# Notifications not shown in Android Froyo

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to run the following, which is ripped from an internet tutorial:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected

    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiveAndGoHome.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, homeIntent, 0);


    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Fraz Go Home!!!")
            .setContentTitle("Fraz Go Home!!!")
            .setContentText("Fraz Go Home!!!")
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();


    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
      (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    notificationManager.notify(25, noti); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
}
```

When I run the above in a froyo AVD, I do not see a notification appear at all - am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the small icon. Add this:

```
.setSmallIcon (R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

somewhere in your `NotificationCompat.Builder` chain of methods.

Of course, the launcher drawable is what I used there since it's on hand, you will need to make actual notification icons for a proper UI. This is just to demo the method call you need.

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) outlines what you need for a Notification to show:

> **Required notification contents**
>
> A Notification object *must* contain
> the following:
>
> • A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
>
> • A title, set by setContentTitle()
>
> • Detail text, set by setContentText()